# Kendo UI Angular Grid checkbox list custom filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to create a Kendo Angular grid control on my page with checkbox list filter on a particular column (column configuration filterable:{multi:true} didn't help.) with distinct values of that column. The custom filter I need to implement is a list of checkboxes, as in the wire frame below (only the first column and the filter is the point of focus now).
[image]

The yellow highlighted items in the list are the filter items. I don't see any out of the box feature to enable this. I have already tried with Kendo multiselect control like below to achieve this.

```js
 $scope.registryTypeFilter = function (element) {
        var menu = $(element).parent();
        menu.find(".k-filter-help-text").text("Show records for people working as:");
        menu.find("[data-role=dropdownlist]").remove();

        var multiSelect = element.kendoMultiSelect({            
            dataSource: _.uniq(_.pluck($scope.automationQueueItems.data(), 'RegistryType')),
            itemTemplate: "<input type='checkbox' />(<label ng-bind='\'data.RegistryType\''></label>)",
            tagTemplate:"$scope.dataItem"
        }).data("kendoMultiSelect");

        menu.find("[type=submit]").on("click", { widget: multiSelect }, filterByRegistryTypeAutomationQueue);
    }
```

But multi select control is not what is required. Has anyone tried the same before?

Answer (score 0):

I was using the older version 2014.x.x. The new version 2015.x.x has the support for filterable:{multi:true}. Upgrading to the latest version. That was my way to solve it.